# Why are the buttons popping out of the text instead of beneath it?

Tags: html, layout

http://jsbin.com/ovuci5

To rephrase, the buttons are higher than text - but why don't they expand below it, and instead create an empty space above the text?

(How) can this be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`vertical-align` property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp).

Add:

```
vertical-align: top;
```

to the CSS style for your buttons if you [want them to "pop" the other way](http://jsbin.com/ovuci5/2/).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `vertical-align: middle;` CSS property on the image to achieve your needs

in your case :

```
.plus {
    background-image: url("http://www.veryicon.com/icon/preview/SystemIcons%20for%20Developers/plus%20Icon.jpg");
    display: inline-block;
    height: 32px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 32px;
}
```